# Is there a Linux distribution designed to connect to a Windows network quickly and easily out of the box?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions, active-directory, windows-server

I want to be able to connect these machines to the domain and use active directory on them.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSuse](http://opensuse.org) - right from the install you are able to join domain and use windows authentication.

Comment: I stand corrected..  it looks like you can with Suse.
http://www.novell.com/rc/docrepository/public/37/basedocument.2006-12-20.4125989187/4622044_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [Xandros](http://www.xandros.com/) and you could do it straight out of the box

> Xandros solutions manage multi-platform data center applications, deliver enterprise-grade email, and create rich user experiences on a range of devices. Millions of people worldwide use our award-winning enterprise, consumer and community products every day.